# Why is this javascript incorrect?

Tags: javascript, rubymine

My IDE, RubyMine, says this is "potentially incorrect":

```
function update_top_up_prices_via_localStorage(){
    var index = localStorage.getItem("volxs");
    $('.product-inner').each(function(){

        var product = this.getAttribute('data-product-miles');
        var cpm = ((localStorage.getItem("cpm_by_volxs_"+product)).split(","))[index];

        $(this).find('table tbody tr td').each(function(){
            var top_up_miles = Number(this.getAttribute('data-topup-miles'));
            var price = Number(top_up_miles * cpm * 1.06);
            price = price.toFixed(2);
            $(this).text('\u00A3'+price);
        })
    });
}
```

My IDE says on the `var top_up_miles` line, "potentially invalid use of `this`. This checks for javascript `this` to be the same in closure as in the outer context.

The js works fine in Chrome and IE9. It does not work in IE8.

Is this wrong? Is there a better way to write this?

Comment: I don't know about RubyMine (actually no idea what that is), but your code looks more or less fine. Strange mix of pure JavaScript and jQuery though. Try using `$(this).attr('data-topup-miles')`. And what do you mean by `It does not work in IE8`? Any errors? Incorrect values (IE8 seems to treat `toFixed` in a different manner then other browsers)? Also IE8 has console (`F12` I believe) - check for errors there (you actually need to fire console before loading page I think).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RubyMine doesn't know that `$().each` executes the passed function with a specified `this` context. If you want to avoid that warning, use

```
$(/* ... */).each(function (i, elem) { 
    elem.getAttribute(/* ... */);
});
```

etc.

The reason your code doesn't work with IE8 probably has nothing to do with that. For greater compatability however, use jQuery-wrapped functions instead of native API functions: `$(this).attr` instead of `this.getAttribute` (thanks @freakish)

Answer (score 1):

It draws your attention to warn you that you should be careful with using the `this` keyword in JavaScript, as `this` always refers to the function owner.

To learn more, see [this article on quirksmode on the JavaScript `this` keyword](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html).

Comment: You explicity set `this` by using `Function.call` or `Function.apply`. This is what jQuery does here.

Comment: @OttoAllmendinger - That may be true, but irrelevant. I was merely addressing to the OP's wonder about the IDE warning. Thanks for the feedback, nice answer BTW